# ls -al list order re-arranged on osx terminal - can't we do this?

Tags: macos, ls

Does anyone know a way to re-arrange the ls -al returned list in a way that:

**a) Directories first, files after;**

and

**b) Date first, name second and permissions at the end**

and

**c) Without losing color.** (CLICOLOR=1 do exist)

and

**d) All this on a ls -al alias ?**

Comment: -1 Question shows no research effort (at least the `awk` part).

Comment: Doesn't answer all parts of the question, but a simple solution to get `group-directories-first` is to install the GNU Coreutils.  See: http://superuser.com/questions/545479/how-can-i-list-directories-first-in-the-terminal-with-zsh-ls-command-in-mac-os

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
ls -la --color=yes --group-directories-first | awk '{print $6 "\t" $8 "\t\t" $1}'
```

About the alias, aliases cannot contain variables, but a solution would be functions. They are stored in `.profile/.bashrc` and work just like aliases.

EDIT: Function is below - just add it to your `.profile`, open a new shell and type `myls`. Works like a charm :)

```
myls () { ls -la --color=yes --group-directories-first | awk '{print $6 "\t" $8 "\t\t" $1}'; }
```

Comment: Doesn't work. ls: illegal option -- -
usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]

Comment: If I simple do: ls -la --group-directories-first it doesn't work. Perhaps it's a mac osx limitation that doesn't other on some others nix distros.

Comment: Heh I just took a look at the ls manual under OSX and indeed it misses the options with --. Couldn't find other options to replace these though...

Comment: Thanks Silviu. Actually this is a start but, if I use this, I loose the colors. :( http://superuser.com/questions/109537/unix-ls-how-to-sort-first-directories-then-files-etc

Comment: ah cool so how about `ls -laG | grep "^d" | awk '{print $6 "\t" $8 "\t\t" $1}' && ls -laG | grep -v "^d" | awk '{print $6 "\t" $8 "\t\t" $1}'`

Comment: Silviu, I'm really sorry for bother you again. :( Can you please check my question update. I see no creation date and, the list gets outlined somehow. Please advice.

Comment: @MEM `ls` has never listed creation date.

Comment: @Daniel Beck here is a line of an ls -la : -rw-r--r--   1 mem  staff     0B Oct 15  2011 .localized   - Oct 15 2011 being a date. Perhaps a creation or modified date. Cheers.

Comment: Silviu: I want to thank you for your work. I will not use unfortunately your suggestion but it sure answers the question. Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: No prob. Have fun! :)

Comment: @MEM It's either modification or change date, and not creation. That is what I was commenting on.