# How can I list directories first in the terminal with zsh / ls command in Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, shell, zsh

Most of the similar questions / answers here don't work in Mac/OSX because there is not such a thing as --options.

I am using the ZSH shell, I've been trying commands said here: http://www.rayninfo.co.uk/tips/zshtips.html but without success.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you're still looking for this, the macOS command line is open source. It's easy to add the option to `ls` on Mac. https://github.com/torstenvl/betterls

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of [hacking around and parsing `ls` output](https://superuser.com/questions/109537/how-to-sort-first-directories-then-files-etc-when-using-ls-in-unix/109564#109564)—which is never a good idea—you could simply install the [GNU Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/), which give you the GNU versions of `ls`, `date`, `echo`, `head` and `tail`, and many more, which offer much more than the BSD counterparts.

The easiest way to do that would be to [install Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), and then run `brew install coreutils`. Now, the GNU coreutils will be available prefixed with a `g`, and you could run:

```
gls -l --group-directories-first
```

Or, you could even alias that in your `.zshrc`:

```
alias ls='gls --group-directories-first'
```

Comment: It worked like a charm:) the only thing is that I lose my zsh colors/settings.(obviously) - A simple note for other persons, I had macports and a warning about possible conflict with homebrew but had no problem. I'm new to Mac / and not much more advanced in UNIX ecosystems so noob inside.

Comment: You shouldn't really need to use both, I guess MacPorts also has a Coreutils port? But if it works, then you're fine :) As for the colors, you can try running `gls --color=auto`.

Comment: `gls --color=auto` does the trick for me. Thanks for the this answer!